# Node.js + Mongoose consume all memory on inserts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memory-leaks, express, mongoose

I need to fill Mongo collection with about 80 million of records like

```
//Example
{
    "_id" : "4gtvCPATZ",
    "isActivated" : false
}
```

Where _id is randomly generated. I do this using Node.js Express and Mongoose:

```
app.get('/api/codes', function(req, res) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        var code = new Code({
            _id: randomStr(9),
            isActivated: 0
        });
        code.save();
        code = null;        
    }
    res.render('index');
});

function randomStr(m) {
    var m = m || 9;
    s = '', r = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz123456789';
    for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        s += r.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * r.length));
    }
    return s;
};
```

On 'index' jade layout has JS code that reloads the page to generate next 100000 records:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
  location.href='http://localhost:3000/api/codes'
```

node.js process starts to consume memory and after 4-5 page reloads hangs up having 1GB of memory.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:
Considering the robertklep's comment I've updated the code and it works properly:

```
app.get('/api/codes', function(req, res) {
var count = 0;
async.whilst(
    function () { return count < 100000; },
    function (callback) {
        count++;
        var code = new Code({
            _id: randomStr(9),
            isActivated: 0
        });     
        code.save(function(){
            callback();             
        });
    },
    function (err) {
        res.render('index');
    }
);
});
```

**UPDATE 2**: I've tested the freakish's advice and made my app work faster:

```
var MongoDB = require("mongodb");
app.get('/api/codes', function(req, res) {
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , format = require('util').format;

  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/code', function(err, db) {
    var collection = db.collection('codes');

    var count = 0;
    async.whilst(
        function () { return count < 10; },
        function (callback) {
            count++;
            var docs = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                docs.push({
                    _id: randomStr(9),
                    isActivated: 0
                });
            }
            collection.insert(docs, function(err, docs) {
                callback();
            });
        },
        function (err) {
            res.render('index');
        }
    );

  })
});
```

Now it writes about 1M records in 60-70 seconds.

Thanks!

Comment: You're inserting 100K records *in parallel*. Also, you're not passing a callback to `save` which will probably cause memory leaks in Mongoose. But the main question is: why!?

Comment: Thanks for answer. You are right: I do this parallel and it's bad. What is the best way to do this one by one?

Comment: One way would be to use [`async.whilst`](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilsttest-fn-callback).

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-inserts/ Use native driver and pass an array of documents to `.insert`.